# "Find References" does text search instead of finding the specific entity

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I used to use an add-in for VS that provided its own "Find references" feature and it worked well. Now I'm using out of the box VS 2015, and the VS "Find References" command seems to simply do a full-text search for the name of the identifier I selected instead of searching for this entity only. Example: I right-click `info.fileName`, where `info` is an object and `filename` is its data member and select "Find References". It finds all the encounters of the `fileName` string, like a method signature: `void setLocalCertificate(const QString &fileName, QSsl::EncodingFormat format = QSsl::Pem)`. I expect it to only find encounters of the `fileName` field of this class.

Is that just how it works, or am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to make this feature work without add-ins? What I get now seems to be equivalent to `Ctrl+Shift+F`. Odd.